# Is there an easy way to copy libraries between projects on netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

Often I find that I have a set of JAR files configured as libraries in one Netbeans project and I need the same (or a subset of) those JAR files in another project.

All of the ways I've found to do this so far are very long winded and painful so I am hoping I've missed something simple.

Google found a 6 year old feature request and nothing else really useful: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=118325

At the moment the ways I can think of are:

Create a "Library" for the set of JARS and then use that library in each project. This is probably the neatest way to do this but still involves a lot of steps and seems like massive overkill just to copy a few JAR file references!

Go to source project, right click JAR, select edit. See the library classpath in the popup window. Close window, go to the destination, select add JAR. Can't cut and paste in path so have to hope you remembered it right. Browse to JAR file, add it - repeat for any other JARs that are not in the same folder.

Frustratingly the tooltip that comes up when you hover over the library contains exactly the path you need to add the jar - but there is no way I can find to copy the contents of that tooltip!

This is all made much more painful by the fact that all the windows are modal, you can't cut and paste the path out because it doesn't actually copy as a real path, etc.

All suggestions welcome as this is becoming a frequent annoyance at the moment!

Comment: Use Maven or another dependency management package. Create a parent pom. Otherwise copying a blob of jars doesn't really seem that onerous.

Comment: Maven has never caused me anything but pain so now I avoid it unless forced to use it. The problem is that you can't copy a blob of JARS - I'd be entirely happy if I could. If you try and select them to copy from one project to another like you would a .java file (for example) it won't let you copy them. You need to individually find the path for the jar, add that jar, then either hope the other jars are in the same folder or go back and repeat.

Comment: Well, this is exactly what Maven is designed for. If you do no want to use Maven then you are left with Ant library management which is, as you have discovered, woeful. It is somewhat improved by Ivy but if you do not want to use Maven then using a crippled version of the Maven library system via Ant seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Then create an uber-jar using any of a zillion tools for this and use that single jar instead of multiple jars. Doing transitive dependency management by hand is nuts, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton +1 for nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this old question while searching for an answer to the same problem.  I Couldn't find any other useful results so I copied the libraries in the `nbproject/project.properties` file to the same place in  my new project.

The only references I found in the whole directory were like this

```
file.reference.commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar=D:\\Documents\\javaLibraries\\commons-lang\\commons-lang3-3.8.1\\commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar
file.reference. [.....many more]
includes=**
jar.compress=false
javac.classpath=\
    ${file.reference.commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar}:\
    [....many more]:\
```

This part was just in between what I wanted, so I copied the whole thing but it was the same in the new project.

```
includes=**
jar.compress=false
```

So far it's all working fine.  You could back up the project.properties file but I already had one nightly.

edit:
You can also copy over the javadoc and sources by copying the lines like

```
javadoc.reference.commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar=D:\\Documents[more path....]javadoc.jar
source.reference.commons-lang3-3.8.1.jar=D:\\Documents[more path....]sources.jar
```